# UmbracoTemplatePage and strongly typed view not working together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, umbraco7, strongly-typed-view

I don't quite understand why I can't use both strongly typed view and umbraco template in one view.

I have a script importing excel data. My website is in umbraco 7.
I use Import.cshtml view which calls upload.cshtml partial

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";

    var locations = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "location 1", Value = ""},
        };

    var fileTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
        new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "type 1", Value = ""},
        };
}

<div id="page-bgtop">
    <div class="post">
        <h1>@Umbraco.Field("title")</h1>
        <div class="entry">
            @Html.Partial("Upload", new MvcImport.Models.ImportModel { FileTypes = fileTypes, Locations = locations })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
```

Upload.cshtml partial does the job in ImportController. The data are there inserted into nicely into

```
List<CourseImport> courses = List<CourseImport>
```

All I want to do with it now is to display them in a view or partial view.
I tried several things:

---

CASE 1

1.

in ImportController I do:

```
return View("CoursesList", courses);
```

2.

The view includes a table which displays the rows and starts with

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
@model IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.CourseImport>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";
}
```

3.

In this case I get:

```
Parser Error Message: The 'inherits' keyword is not allowed when a 'model' keyword is used.
```

---

CASE 2

1.

As 1. in Case 1.

2.

The view starts with (so without @inherits UmbracoTemplatePage)

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.CourseImport>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";
}
```

3.

I get:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MvcImport.Models.CourseImport]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel'.
```

---

CASE 3

1.

In ImportController I do

```
return PartialView("CoursesList", courses);
```

2.

I'm now using partial view which it similar to the view in the above points and also is strongly typed eg.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcImport.Models.CourseImport>
```

3.

In this case the data is displayed but without my umbraco template shape, no styling etc.

If in the partial view I include

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Master.cshtml";
}
```

I get the same error as in Case 2

---

Changing the starting directive to

```
@model UmbracoViewPage<MvcImport.Models.CourseImport>
```

does not work either as the model must be enumerable

---

Can someone advise me how to do it? I guess there must be a solution but I am very new to MVC so I don't get how things work yet too much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is provided on umbraco forum website http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/55389-UmbracoTemplatePage-and-strongly-typed-view-not-working-together?p=0